# Check if SEO plugin installed

Tags: plugins, seo

Is there any way to check whether the user has an SEO plugin installed, so as if they do not I can insert my metas etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi **@Liam:**,

What you are going to need to do is create a list of the top SEO plugins and themes and then document how each implements meta and develop a strategy for each. And/or maybe you can ask your users upon activation if they are using an SEO plugin much like Akismet asks users to enter an API key.

Comment: Aha, good idea. And I can add an option to disable my theme's SEO functionality.

Comment: @Liam Bailey: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the plugin folder name + filename where the plugin is initiated like this for example YOAST plugin:

```
if(in_array('wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins')))){ 
    /* Yoast is active */
}
```

OR find the main class of the plugin and check agains that like:

```
if(class_exists('WPSEO_Options')){
    /* Yoast is active */
    if(WPSEO_Options::get('breadcrumbs-enable', false)){
        /* Yoast breadcrumbs is active */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for specific plugin(s), for example with [`is_plugin_active()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active) function.

But there is no way to check for SEO plugin in general, at least not in any kind of reliable way.